# In python, how can I get functions such as repr() to work with my proxy class?

Tags: python, factory-pattern, proxy-classes, repr

I have devised a proxy class that allows me to replace any type/class with a factory method and still retain most of the functionality of the class object. Here is a sample of how it works:

```
class ProxyClass:
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self._ProxyClass_cls = cls
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._ProxyClass_cls, name)

class _strProxy(ProxyClass):
    def __call__(self, s):
        if '\n' in s:
            raise ValueError
        if s not in self._cache:
            self._cache[s] = self._ProxyClass_cls(s)
        return self._cache[s]

str = _strProxy(str)
str._cache = {}


>>> s = str('hello')
>>> s
'hello'
>>> type(s)
<type 'str'>
>>> str('hello\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __call__
ValueError
```

I like this implementation of factory methods because it completely replaces the original class object and still allows things like the following:

```
>>> map(str.split, [str('foo bar'), str('bar foo')])
[['foo', 'bar'], ['bar', 'foo']]
```

The only problem I have found is with operations on the class itself such as `repr()`:

```
>>> repr(str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor '__repr__' of 'str' object needs an argument
```

In this example, `repr()` is attempting to call `str.__repr__()` rather than `type.__repr__(str)`. I tried fixing changing `str.__class__` but found out that this is impossible in this case:

```
>>> str.__class__ = type
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __class__ must be set to a class
```

Does anyone know of any way to restore the functionality of `repr(str)` or maybe another way to accomplish what I am doing?

Comment: It is best in cases like this to post actual working code that we can copy/paste into a text file and execute.  The above has `>>>` and `...` that must be edited out, and the above has a typo in it that makes it not work correctly even after the extra stuff is edited out.

Comment: @steveha Ok, I will edit it. What is the typo?

Comment: You have fixed the typo now.  The class `_strProxy()` used to be `_strPproxy()`.  (The calls were to `_strProxy()`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that all your classes inherit from `object`:

```
class ProxyClass(object):
```

In Python 3.x, all classes inherit from `object` anyway, so you don't need to do this.  But in Python 2.x, the inheritance stuff doesn't work right unless all the classes involved are "new-style classes" that inherit from `object`.

`repr(str)` works fine for me after making the above change.

Comment: This has the same effect as Jakob's answer. You now cannot access the `__repr__` (or any of `object`'s methods) of the original `str`.

Comment: @Matt, the question shows binding the name `str` with a wrapped class.  I wouldn't do that, myself; I would make a new class with a new name.  But I am tired today, and I just answered the question instead of going full-on teacher mode.

Even if you did rebind `str`, here is a way to access the `__repr__()` method of the original builtin `str`:  `type('').__repr__(s)`

Comment: I dont intend to rebind built-ins like `str`, I just used it as an example. This is really for my own classes which I intend to define and rebind (probably with a decorator). This seems to be the only way I can come up with to override the constructor with a factory function and still make the class accessible as a class.

Comment: It's generally true in Python that you can explicitly ask for a method from a class directly.  Like, suppose `s` is a variable which is an instance of a class derived from `str` and you want to print it using the `repr()` of `str`, you can do this:  `str.__repr__(s)`  More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465070/are-python-object-functions-singletons/7465126#7465126

Answer (score 0):

Why not do

```
>>> class _strPproxy(ProxyClass):
...     def __call__(self, s):
...         self.s = s
...         if '\n' in s:
...             raise ValueError
...         if s not in self._cache:
...             self._cache[s] = self._ProxyClass_cls(s)
...         return self._cache[s]
...     def __repr__(self): 
...         return repr(self.s)
```

Comment: Because then you lose access to the actual str.__repr__ (although I am not sure whether having this access is necessary).

Comment: Well you could have `__original_repr__` as the `str.__repr__`